# Cordova + Firebase auth + ISO Cannot open the page because the address is invalid

Tags: firebase, cordova, vue.js, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

Currently I'm developing mobile application using Cordova framework,firebase  OAuth to signing through google. all stuff work correctly.on android but when i run app on ios platform.
I got the following Error during redirection process for google signin

**Safari Cannot open the page because the address is invalid**

Config.xml setting :

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" spec="4.3.0">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="*****.firebaseapp.com" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_SCHEME" value=" " />
    <variable name="ANDROID_HOST" value=" " />
    <variable name="ANDROID_PATHPREFIX" value="/" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-universal-links-plugin" spec="https://github.com/walteram/cordova-universal-links-plugin" />
<universal-links>
    <host name="***.page.link" scheme="https" />
    <host name=|******.firebaseapp.com" scheme="https">
        <path url="/__/auth/callback" />
    </host>
</universal-links>
```

**javascript code :**

```
 var fireProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithRedirect(fireProvider)
    .then(function() {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true)
        .then(function(idToken) {
          console.info("idToken", idToken);
          var payload = { idToken: idToken };
          //do something 
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.info(
            "error.message",
            error.message,
            "errorCode",
            error.code
          );

        });
    });
```

any thought why this error happen

Thanks a lot

**Update :**
It was problem about **some mistakes during setup** I fix as following :

- follow the instruction:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova
- make sure that you  **Dynamic Links**, **AUTH_DOMAIN**, **DYNAMIC_LINK_DOMAIN** and **URL_SCHEME** all are correct.